# Dishes database relations

Tags: database, t-sql, database-design

I want to create database with recipes. How it should look like?

For example let it exist two recipes:

First recipe: 2 eggs with chees.

Second recipe: 3 eggs with chees and beans.

The main proble different types of dishes can contain different types of ingredients(chees,beans,other) how it should be organized in database? I think that every ingredient should have own ID (ingredientID). But how it's id should connect to dish?

Dish table:

```
DishID DishName DishType
```

Table with ingredients:

```
DishType IngredientID
```

But in this case every dish should have only one ingredient, how to build table where dish can contain two or more ingredients?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In RDBMS it is a standard Many-to-Many scenario. You need to have a middle table to represent the "many" relationship, something like:

```
Create table DishIngredient
(
DishIngredientID int identity(1, 1) primary key,
DishID int,
IngredientID int,
Amount int,
)
```